# How to save correct filename through proxy page

Tags: proxy, filenames

I´m a newbie. Trying to develop my knowledge around PHP and JavaScript. This time I´ve banged my head too many times and searched for answers long enough.

I´m trying to create a proxy page to view PDFs. It works! But when I want to save the file it names itself "proxy.pdf". On my Transformer Prime tablet it downloads the script: "proxy.php" instead.

This is how my Proxy PHP code looks like:

```
<?php

session_start;

// define path to image folder
$image_folder = realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/imagefolder/";
// get image name from the query string
// no probe
if (isset($_GET['pic']) && basename($_GET['pic']) == $_GET['pic'])
{   
    $pic = $image_folder.$_GET['pic'];
    if (file_exists($pic) && is_readable($pic)) 
    {
        // get the filename extension
        $ext = substr($pic, -3);
        // set the MIME type
        switch ($ext)
        {
    case 'jpg':
    $mime = 'image/jpeg';
    break;
    case 'gif':
    $mime = 'image/gif';
    break;
    case 'png':
    $mime = 'image/png';
    break;
    case 'pdf':
    //alt octet-stream
    $mime = 'application/pdf';
    break;
    default:
    $mime = false;
    } 
    // if a valid MIME type exists, display the image 
    // by sending appropriate headers and streaming the file
    if ($mime)
    {

        header('Content-type: '.$mime);
        header('Content-length: '.filesize($pic));

        $file = fopen($pic, 'rb');
        if ($file)
        {
            fpassthru($file);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this when I had the same question for my ASP.NET app.  Using the [Content-Disposition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) header is what did it for me. I won't pretend to be a PHP expert but if you add this line next to your other headers it should get the job done.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$_GET['pic']);
```